# Populate Table using DreamFactory API & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dreamfactory

I am trying to populate a products table with products that belong to only one restaurant, so far I managed to populate the restaurant table, but when I click on the restaurant it doesn't show the products that belong to that place. I am following the code provided in here: https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/javascript-sdk

So far I got to this, regarding the products table

route.js

```
            case 'restaurantes':
                setButton('left', template, 'index', 'redirect', null);

                $.api.getRecords('restaurante', null, getToken('token'), populateRestaurantesTable);
                break;

            case 'produto_show':
                setButton('left', template, 'restaurantes', 'redirect', null);
                setButton('right', template, 'restaurantes/' + pathArray[1] + '/edit', 'redirect', null);

                var params = 'filter=id%3D' + pathArray[1] + '&fields=nomeRestaurante';
                $.api.getRecords('produto', params, getToken('token'), populateProdutoShowName);

                break;
```

script.js

```
    var tableProduto = $('#table_produto').DataTable({
    "paging":   false,
    "info":     false,
    "order": [
        [2, "asc" ],
        [3, "asc"],
        [1, "asc"]
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        { "visible": false, "targets": 0 },
        { "visible": false, "targets": 2 },
        { "visible": false, "targets": 3 }
    ],

    "drawCallback": function () {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
        var last=null;

        api.column(2, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( produto, i ) {
            if ( last !== produto) {
                $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                    '<tr class="produto info"><td colspan="4">'+produto+'</td></tr>'
                );

                last = produto;
            }
        } );

        $("#table_produto thead").remove();
        $("#table_produto tfoot").remove();
    }
});

var populateProdutoShowName = function(data) {
    $('#produto_show_name').text(data[0].name);
};


var populateProdutoTable = function(data) {
    var produtos = [];

    $.each(data, function(idProduto, produto){
        produtos.push([
            produto.idProduto,
            produto.nomeProduto + ' ' + produto.precoProduto,
            produto.nomeProduto.charAt(0).toUpperCase(),
            produto.precoProduto
        ])
    });

    $('#table_produto').dataTable().fnClearTable();
    $('#table_produto').dataTable().fnAddData(produtos);
    $('#table_produto').dataTable().fnDraw();
};

$('#table_produto tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var produtoId = $('#table_produto').DataTable().row(this).data();

    if (produtoId !== undefined)
        $.route('produto/' + produtoId[0]);
});

$('#table_produto_search').keyup(function(){
    $('#table_produto').DataTable().search($(this).val(), false, true).draw() ;
});
```

index.html

```
   <div id="template_produto_show">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top df-nav cen col-md-12" role="navigation" style="">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="width: 100%">
                    <li class="pull-left"><button type="button" id="produto_menu_left" class="btn btn-default btn-menu">Voltar</button></li>
                    <li class="pull-left"><button type="button" id="produto_menu_logout" class="btn btn-default btn-menu-logout">Sair</button></li>
                    <li style="float: none; display: inline-block; position: relative; text-align: center"><a href="#index"><img src="Leanline1503-Leanline1503/img/icone.png" height="25"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="row vert-offset-top-30"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8">

                <div style="text-align: center"><h2><span id="produto_show_name"></span></h2></div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="table_produto_search" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar produtos">
                </div>
                <table class="table table-hover" id="table_produto">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
```

The analogy I am making here is that the Groups are my "Restaurantes" and "Group_Show" is to show the Contacts inside the group, which for me is to show the "Produtos" inside the group. 
I don't know if that's all the information one would need to help me, but please let me know if you need more info. Thank you everyone for the time and help!

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the route.js, now it is

```
case 'produto_show':
            setButton('left', template, 'restaurantes', 'redirect', null);
            setButton('right', template, 'restaurantes/' + pathArray[1] + '/edit', 'redirect', null);

            var params = 'filter=restaurante_id_restaurante%3D' + pathArray[1] + '&fields=nomeProduto';
            $.api.getRecords('produto', params, getToken('token'), populateProdutoShowName);

            break;
```